# Where is my 'build' button up on my vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Trying to create a new .keystore in my app, I realized that my vscode's build button just doesn't exist anymore, something like that happened with someone else here, if so, how did you manage to generate a .keystore?

I have only "File Edit Selection View Go Run Terminal Help" up on my vscode. Where's the Build between Go and Run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how your build button disappeared, but normally in vscode, to build your code, you need to define a build task in .vscode\tasks.json for the type of code you want to build, for example, to build .net Core:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
                "build",
                // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+B or running Run Build Task from the global Terminal menu

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: I made an extension for the MIA build button that will run the build task
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ThoughtStuff.build-button